# QGraphicsScene::addItem: item has already been added to this scene

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene

I tried to add several items to QGraphicsScene, but after calling `scene->addItem(new Bonus(Bonus::BonusType::coin, randPoint, pixels, parent));` in application output appears this message: `QGraphicsScene::addItem: item has already been added to this scene`.
What I do wrong?
Code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < coinsCount; ) {
    QPoint randPoint(random() % g->getWidth(),
                     random() % g->getHeight());

    if(g->getType(randPoint) != Graph::wall && !usedPoints.contains(randPoint)) {
        scene->addItem(new Bonus(Bonus::BonusType::coin, randPoint, pixels, parent));
        usedPoints.push_back(randPoint);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are passing a parent item. If the parent item is already added to the scene, setting it as a parent for the new item will add the latter to the scene as well.

The constructor runs before `addItem()` so by the time the latter is executed, the item is already in the scene.

> Note that this implicitly adds this graphics item to the scene of the
>   parent. You should not add the item to the scene yourself.